# Recebe 2 formularios em apenas uma requisiçao POST - Javascript,HTML

Tags: javascript

Estou criando um formulário com 2 etapas em Javascript, em HTML diferentes, da primeira etapa, passa pra segunda pagina de etapa 2, e o da etapa 2 devia enviar como POST os 2 juntos, mas...
O form da etapa 1 acaba sendo enviado como GET pra etapa 2, e ele não armazena da forma que eu queria, sendo assim, apenas o FORM da etapa 2 e enviado como POST...
Podem me dar uma ideia de como posso prosseguir?

Segue os códigos:

```html
<h1>Form etapa 1</h1>
<form action="/etapa2" action="POST">
<label> Nome</label>
<input type="text" name="nome"> <br><br>
<label>Valor</label>
<input type="text" name="mae"><br><br>
<button id="btnTeste">Proximo</button>
</form>
```

```html
<h1>Form etapa 2</h1>
<form action="/finalizado" action="POST">
<label> valor1</label>
<input type="text" name="valor1"> <br><br>
<label>Valor2</label>
<input type="text" name="valor2"><br><br>
<button type="submit">finish</button>
</form>
```

Comment: bom, você provavelmente precisará fazer  o  post via requisição  ajax, desta forma você conseguirá enviar os dois form juntos, concatenando  os campos.

Comment: acha menos complicado utilizar o reactjs para tal projeto como front end?

Comment: Com o Reactjs ficaria mais fácil de utilizar. Você está fazendo o back-end tb? Vejo nisso algumas opções que já utilizei, a primeira seria colocar os dois formulários em uma unica pagina e ficar trocando apenas de div, assim validando e armazenando os valores dos inputs para depois enviar por ajax. A segunda forma dependeria do seu back-end, você poderia realizar uma requisição para outra página e por meio dessa requisição retornar os dados. A terceira opção seria você enviar o input do primeiro form e pegar as querys na segunda página, para isso o primeiro form deve ser method get